# How can I calculate the proportion of students at an institution who are low-income or first-generation?

Tags: collegescorecard, analysis

I would like to use data from the College Scorecard to calculate the proportion of students who are low-income or first-generation at each institution. In the dataset, I only see "number of" low-income and first-generation student variables. How do you recommend I calculate the proportion, if possible? Divide by the number completed in fill-in-the-blank cohort? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the connection of your question to "Open Data"?

Comment: @jknappen - https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/ points people to post here for all things `collegescorecard` ... I have mixed feelings but that's the current situation

Answer (score 2):

These may be the variables are looking for:

- Percentage of aided students whose family income is between $0-$30,000   student share_lowincome.0_30000 float   INC_PCT_LO          NSLDS
- Percentage first-generation students student share_firstgeneration   float   PAR_ED_PCT_1STGEN           NSLDS

Keep in mind these are percentages of title IV aided student cohorts